# Verify email address in Meteor without creating a user account

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

I'm creating a website in Meteor where users can sign up to get notifications using their email address. I want to be able to verify the addresses that are entered, but users do not need to create an account. Is there a way to use the email verification tool built into Meteor without actually using accounts-password, or will I need to somehow create an email verification script from scratch?

Comment: No need for accounts-password. Just use google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680544/meteorjs-email-form-validation

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same functionality some time back but could not find it so I ended up creating my email validaion functions using collection-2/simple-schema on the server side and jqueryValidation plugin client side (in the end I ended up removing jqueryValidation plugin function as it was compromising my security).

The functions validate the existence of the email address in my users collection and not the existence of the email address on some domain on the web - I believe this is the functionality you are looking for as that is what meteor does out of the box. Both simple-schema and jqueryValidation plugin do the regex email validation easily - just see their documentation.

That said, if you however do find that meteor out of the box validation most of us would like to know about it, so please do post it back.